# Unable to connect to postgres database AWS RDS using pgx

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds, pgx

I am trying to connect to postgres database in AWS RDS in a Go program using `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5` package, but the following error occurs:

```
failed to connect to `host=xxxxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com user=golangpg database=golangpg`: server error (FATAL: database "golangpg" does not exist (SQLSTATE 3D000))
exit status 1
```

Even its explicit that database not exist is the error but I have already created the RDS database and I also can connect to that database through **pgAdmin** as well. But when I tried to connect in my Go code, I got the above mentioned error.

I have checked the following points

1. Security group is allowing all traffic through 5432 port
2. Public access is enabled in the RDS
3. Able to connect through pgAdmin to the same database.

```
     
    package database
    
    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strconv"
    
        "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
        "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    )
    
    func PGConnection() *pgx.Conn {
        envErr := godotenv.Load()
        if envErr != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error in loading .env file, ", envErr)
        }
    
        host := os.Getenv("DB_URL")
        port := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
        user := os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME")
        password := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
        dbname := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
    
        portInt, er := strconv.Atoi(port)
        if er != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error in converting string to number", er)
        }
    
        var err error
    
        pgConnString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require", host, portInt, user, password, dbname)
    
        pgConn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), pgConnString)
    
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Unable to connection to database: \n%v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Database connection establised to db ", dbname)
        }
    
        return pgConn
    }
    
    var Connection *pgx.Conn = PGConnection()
```

What could be the error here. Even from pgAdmin I can able to create tables but couldn't connect from my Go code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 'database "golangpg" does not exist (SQLSTATE 3D000)' means it is connecting to the database.

Comment: Nope its going to the err != nil statement and printing "Unable to connection to database" and the above given error

Comment: The error says `database "golangpg" does not exist` (in RDS) but you said it exist and was able to access it from pgAdmin? Can you do and add `telnet <rdsHost> 5432` to confirm that RDS is (publicly) accessible?  Can you also add a screenshot that show `golangpg` DB existing in the RDS host?

Comment: @TsalTroser I have updated the question with the required screenshots

Comment: Interesting part is when I give ```pgConnString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=postgres sslmode=require", host, portInt, user, password)
``` dbname as postgres its connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `database "golangpg" does not exist` in your RDS PostgreSQL host.

`RDS identifier != database name`

---

**Here I re-create your setup:**

**PostgreSQL RDS**

[image]

**Executed the same code and got the same error:**

```
▶ go run main.go
Unable to connection to database: 
failed to connect to `host=golangdb.xxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com user=postgres database=golangdb`: server error (FATAL: database "golangdb" does not exist (SQLSTATE 3D000))
exit status 1
```

The reason is `database "golangdb" does not exist` doesn't exist in my PostgreSQL RDS.

**Connect to the database host and list the available databases.**

```
▶ psql --host=golangdb.xxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --username=postgres

postgres=> \l
                                                       List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Locale Provider |   Collate   |    Ctype     
-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 
 rdsadmin  | rdsadmin | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8
```

This is also why using `dbname := "postgres"` works, because the database exist in the host.

```
▶ go run main.go
Database connection establised to db  postgres
```

**Create new database**

```
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE golangdb;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=> \l
                                                       List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Locale Provider |   Collate   |    Ctype    
-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------
 golangdb  | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 
 rdsadmin  | rdsadmin | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8
```

**Retry go code**

```
▶ go run main.go
Database connection establised to db  golangdb
```

Comment: Yeah when we creating RDS, within the additional configuration section we need to specify the initial database name otherwise it wont create by its own.  postgres and rdsadmin will come by default. When connecting through pgAdmin I have defined the Maintenance database as postgres so its connected properly. Main catch is DB Identifier and database nam both are difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try `database=%s` instead of `dbname=%s`, and [pass](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/samples/cloud-sql-postgres-databasesql-connect-tcp-sslcerts) necessary certs when using `sslmode=require`.

Comment: No still getting the same error